# Trying to use Ethernet over Bluetooth between Pi boards

Tags: ssh, bluetooth, ethernet

I'm trying to use SSH over Bluetooth via *Ethernet over Blutooth.* I've based my effort thus far on: [Bluetooth PAN Network Setup with BlueZ 5.X](http://blog.fraggod.net/2015/03/28/bluetooth-pan-network-setup-with-bluez-5x.html)

I believe I have faithfully followed the instructions. The instruction require server and client side systemd services be created:
net-bnep.service and net-bnep-client.service, respectively.

In addition, there's [bt-pan](https://github.com/mk-fg/fgtk/blob/master/bt-pan), a Python script (courtsey of GiTHub). The script is invoked on both sides. Finally, there's a bridge to be created as the "connection point":

```
#!/bin/bash

br=bnep

[[ -n "$(brctl show $br 2>&1 1>/dev/null)" ]] && {
  brctl addbr $br
  brctl setfd $br 0
  brctl stp $br off
  ip addr add 10.1.2.3/24 dev $br
  ip link set $br up
}

exec bt-pan --debug server $br
```

When I try to check on the status of the server side service, everything appears OK. But on the client side, the service is dead with the message

> Method "Connect" with signature 's' on org.bluez.Network1 doesn't exist.

Using ***d-feet*** it couldn't find a service **org.bluez.Network1**, let alone a method *Connect*.

Anyone besides me trying to accomplish the same thing?

BTW, if you look at the latest BlueZ on GitHub, you'll see it includes a suite of test utilities, one in particular: ***bneptest***. This utility supposedly can be used for the same purpose, Ethernet over Bluetooth.

I cloned, built, and installed the Git repository. Now trying ***bneptest***.

Comment: ethernet and LAN are not interchangeable terms ..... you may have better luck googling `LAN over bluetooth`

Comment: I just used the term “Ethernet over Bluetooth” because I saw others using it. I guess the proper term is “BNEP over L2CAP”.  Tho I’m not really focused on what it’s called.

Comment: all i am saying is that the answer you seek may be on the internet, but it may not show up when you search for Ethernet over Bluetooth

Comment: I’ve searched under every possible combination of names I could think of: “pan Bluetooth”, “Bluetooth tcp/ip”, “Bluetooth ssh”, etc. The best that showed up was that article I sent a link to.

Comment: And it’s the only one to address BlueZ5, which is quite different than its predecessors.

Comment: Oftentimes, networking over Bluetooth is called a PAN, for Personal Area Networking.